# How many pages will a free 128kb Xamarin Starter Edition app hold?

Tags: cordova, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

Looking to build a cross platform (Windows 10 App, iOS and Android) app with a guide for our 50 products. How many pages will a free 128kb Xamarin Starter Edition app hold? Just looking to add some text for each product with product description, screenshot and perhaps a link to a youtube video for each product.

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin Starter was made to *get a **taste** of mobile development in C#*. It's almost impossible to build a productive app in this edition. Xamarin Starter can also be called a *demo version*.

It's impossible to answer your question with a definite number of pages. It depends strongly on the frameworks you use (e.g. MvvmCross) to build your app and how much data is stored in it. It'd be really challenging to build an app with descriptions and screenshots for 50 products with less than 128kb. 
You will definitely become frustrated as you will exceed that small limit many times. 
I suggest you not trying to do it.

Comment: Shame, Xamarin could be a lot better without this restriction.